# I can't type in terminal after running discord bot

Tags: javascript, terminal, discord

Q: What should i do?

This also happens in command prompt. I use Visual Studio code, and the bot is written in javascript.

I'm currently following this tutorial on youtube, and i really new to javascript.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbbLC0BLaGjpyzN1rg-gK4dUqbn8eJQq4

Main.js:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '+';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Lama is online!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'kick'){
        client.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args);
    } else if(command === 'youtube'){
        client.commands.get('youtube').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login('token here');
```

I always start the bot with "node ."
I can't post image, sorry.

And after the console sends "Lama is online!"
I can't type there.

Comment: Is it because the app is still running?

Comment: The app is running, but i cannot type there or turn it off.

Comment: You can't type *because* the app is running. That's just how the console works. To stop the app, try ctrl-c.